# Am I violating copyright by sharing photos of pages of books I read or quoting them?

Tags: copyright

I read a lot of books, and when I come across an interesting part, I take a photo and share it on my social media.
I also do book reviews on my blog which always includes some paragraphs from the book I'm writing about.
I also always do mention the name, and the author of the book in both cases.
Am I violating the copyright law?
Thanks

Comment: Related: [Copyright issues with grammar literature quotations on ELL StackExchange](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7017/copyright-issues-with-grammar-literature-quotations-on-ell-stackexchange)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on jurisdiction but in most places you can use excerpts for the purpose of review without any problem. Attribution helps. The exact amount you can quote is rarely specified by rather it is whatever is judged to be reasonable and necessary for the review without hurting the income of the copyright holder.

Answer (score 0):

Under US law, limited quotations for the purpose of review of and commentary on the work quoted is generally permitted as a "fair use". The copyright law of other countries generally has somewhat similar provisions, but the details vary quite a bit.

As another answer said, there is no general rule on how much can be quoted, it depends on the exact situation. Good practice is to use only as much as is clearly required to make the point and help the reader understand the review, and never to use so much as to harm the market for the original work. Therefore a narrowly limited quote of the relevant part is better than a picture of a page, which is likely to include more than is needed for the purpose. And of course, always attribute your quotes to their sources. This is ethically essential, whether required by copyright law or not. It may also help a case for fair use, by demonstrating the transformative purpose, and by  directing the reder to the original source, thus reducing any harm to the market for the original source.

Comment: The ethical essentials also include adopting ideas and facts from other works, where you should give credit where credit is due. But copyright law does not include any protection for ideas and facts. You ethical essential is under-developed and distracts from the legal issue.

Comment: Yes, there are other ethical essentials. This specifically involves quotations, and it also has legal/copyright implications, which i have now emphasized.